# what does glMultMatrixf(matrix, offset) do?

Tags: graphics, opengl-es, matrix, translation

I'm reading through the code in Android SDK. This is for setting up modelview:

```
    // set-up modelview matrix
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
    gl.glLoadIdentity();
    gl.glTranslatef(0, 0, -3.0f);
    gl.glMultMatrixf(mRotationMatrix, 0);
```

What does the last line of code mean? I've not found some definite answer in the internet. There are plenty, however, about  `void glMultMatrixf( const GLfloat *m )` .

Rotation Matrix:

```
    private final float[] mRotationMatrix = new float[16];
    mRotationMatrix[ 0] = 1;
    mRotationMatrix[ 4] = 1;
    mRotationMatrix[ 8] = 1;
    mRotationMatrix[12] = 1;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the proper documentation finally.

> matrix - Specifies an array of at least 16 consecutive values, the
>   first 16 of which are used as the elements of a 4 × 4 column-major
>   matrix. offset - the starting offset within the m array.

more [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/opt-pkgs/api/jb/jsr239/javax/microedition/khronos/opengles/GL10.html#glMultMatrixf%28float%5B%5D,%20int%29)